# import and sort data by certain rows in python

Tags: python, sorting, text

I am fairly new to python and I'm not sure what the best way is to approach this issue. I have a text file that has 400 000 rows of data and each row has 21 columns. My desired task is to classify or sort the data by rows 4 and 5 which are latitude and longitude. I want the sorted data to be stored or appended to something (ie. variable or empty array) so that I can extract the sorted data for further processing. First I need to import the data and I'm not sure what the best way is to do that.

Overview:

1. Import text file data?
2. Convert to array or matrix for manipulation
3. Classify on certain keys
4. Store classified data in (bins, empty arrays, or variables)

Comment: How are the columns delimited? Could you post a few sample lines of your data file for us to work with?

Comment: you might run into memory issues, we need to know what manipulation you need so that we can load certain chunks into memory at a time for manipulation

Comment: they are space delimited, but i could transfer them to csv if neccessary. and my plan is to only procces maybe a third of the data to start off. unfortunatly i will not be able to post any of the data

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest using the pandas library for this, you can easily import the file, convert it to a dataframe, and then sort it by your two rows using http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html
If you can convert you file into a csv, it will be even easier as you can do `dataframe = pandas.read_csv(file)`. You can then resave the file with `dataframe.to_csv(file)`